# Confused Results: Array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote a little piece of code to test whether the array of pointer is working as I 
expected. Then I got this wired results -- After the third pointer assignment, the array of pointer all point to the last string. Anyone can explain what happened? Thank you.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    char *pstr[10];
    char p[10];
    char *s1 = "morning";
    char s2[10] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    char s3[10] = {'g','o','o','d'};
    int i = 0; 

    strcpy(p, s1);
    pstr[0] = p;
    printf("%s\n", pstr[0]);

    strcpy(p, s2);  
    pstr[1] = p;
    printf("%s\n", pstr[1]);

    strcpy(p, s3);  
    pstr[2] = p;
    printf("%s\n", pstr[2]);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", pstr[i]);
}
```

The output from the program is:

```
morning
hello
good
good
good
good
```

Comment: Make sure you null-terminate your strings.

Comment: U-la-la. I suggest you try one(!) thing at a time. When that works you move on to the next, more difficult example. I get dizzy looking at this code, and if someone corrects it for you, you probably still have a hard time to understand....step-by-step.

Comment: Also make your main return int

Comment: That output is what I'd expect. What did you expect ?

Comment: @Mike Kwan Those strings are null terminated. Since he specify a size for the array of s2 and s3 , and the morning and good initalizers are less than the size, the rest of the characters will be initialized to zero. Though, it'd be clearer and less confusing if he added a nul terminator explicitly

Comment: @Mike: While it is true that `s2` and `s3` should have '\0' or an equivalent explicitly added to the ends of the character arrays, just in case and to make it clearer that they are supposed to represent strings, in the situation given I believe the problem is much simpler than that. Other people have already stated it as answers, of course.

Comment: @JAB: Yes, the null termination is not to do with his problem, just something I thought I'd point out.

Comment: @nos: They are not necessarily null terminated. AFAIK uninitialized variables are not guaranteed to be initialized to zero.

Comment: @Mike: I think local variables are guaranteed, but globals aren't. I'd have to double-check.

Comment: Woops, seems I got it backwards. "In C, variables with static storage duration that are not initialized explicitly are initialized to zero (or null, for pointers)."

Comment: @Mike Kwan Yes they are. The variable(array) is initialized, but not all members are. Any members of a struct or array not mentioned in an initializer gets their default value (0 for chars). But if the array had no initializers at all, there would be no guarantee. Even char[1024] = "bar"; would guarantee to fill the remaining 1000 elements with 0.

Comment: @nos : You're right. Didn't realise unitialized variables in C are assigned 0.

Comment: @JAB : if you think about how local variables work it makes sense they will not be assigned 0. You are simply moving the stack pointer so whatever it 'initialised' is simply the last value that was at that address of the stack.

Comment: @Mike Kwan No, I am not saying uninitialized variables are assigned 0. `int a; ` , here a is uninitialized. We do not know what it contains. `char[10] a;` Same here. We don't know what is in a[0] through a[9]. However, with `char a[10] = {'x'};`, then `a` is initialized. a[0] will contain `x`. But, since a[1] through a[9] was not mentioned in the initalizer, they get their default value of 0.

Comment: @nos: And it's a good thing it works that way, too, otherwise the source code of C extensions for Python (and anything else that utilizes large but sparse structs to hold data) would take up a lot more space.

Answer (score 6):

You have set `pstr[0]`, `pstr[1]` and `pstr[2]` to equal `p`.  And the last thing written into `p` is the byte sequence `"good"`.  So at the end, you are essentially printing `p` three times.

Answer (score 4):

All three pointers in the `pstr` array point to the same memory location (`p`).

And since you modify the contents of that memory location a few times using the `strcpy` calls, it will contain whatever was placed there last.

In this case, the string `"good"` was placed there last, so that's what all three pointers in the `pstr` array will point to, and that's what will get displayed repeatedly in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamental point - the array of memory referenced by `p` can only contain one string at a time.

The loop at the end of your code will always print out the same value on each iteration, since you seeded each entry in the array `pstr` with the same pointer `p`.

If you want to see different results on each iteration, you have to point `pstr[0]`, `pstr[1]` and `pstr[2]` to different areas of memory.

Answer (score 2):

pstr[0], pstr[1], and pstr[2] all point to the same 10-character array p. When you copy each string, you change the contents of the array p, but it's address doesn't change. So, after you copied the last string into p, you just end up printing the same thing three times.

Answer (score 2):

not only all the entries of the array are p, but you are `strcpy`'ing non zero terminated strings. `strcpy()` needs the strings to be zero terminated or you'll get a buffer overrun with unpredictable consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you set `pstr[i]=p;` bit `p` is the address of a static buffer.